# Cómo leer cada línea de un archivo json y obtener un diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pandas, python-3.7

Tengo una carpeta en mi escritorio. Necesito leer todos los archivos de texto `JSON` y `html` que tengo allí (Cada `json`, tiene su `html`). El `HTML` tiene el texto original. Del `JSON`, necesitamos extraer una parte específica llamada "entities" y "relations", luego necesitamos obtener un diccionario por cada `json`. Tenemos siete archivos `JSON` en total, incluido el texto `html`.

**Por ejemplo, me gustaría obtener algo como esto, por cada texto JSON y HTML ... En total tenemos siete:**

```
{"text": Html original text,
 "entities": ......,
 "relations: .......
}
```

**Uno de mis JSON se ve así: (Los siete JSON se ven como este)**

```
{
  "annotatable": {
    "parts": ["s1p1"]
  },
  "anncomplete": true,
  "sources": [],
  "metas": {},
  "entities": [
    {
      "classId": "e_2",
      "part": "s1p1",
      "offsets": [
        {
          "start": 3,
          "text": "muy dificil"
        }
      ],
      "coordinates": [],
      "confidence": {
        "state": "pre-added",
        "who": ["user:Moon00"],
        "prob": 1
      },
      "fields": {},
      "normalizations": {}
    },
    {
      "classId": "e_3",
      "part": "s1p1",
      "offsets":[
        {
          "start": 21,
          "text": "comunicacion"
        }
      ],
      "coordinates": [],
      "confidence": {
        "state": "pre-added",
        "who": ["user:sun02"],
        "prob": 1
      },
      "fields": {},
      "normalizations": {}
    }
  ],
  "relations": [
    {
      "classId": "r_5",
      "type": "linked",
      "directed": false,
      "entities": ["s1p1|e_3|21,32", "s1p1|e_2|3,13"],
      "confidence": {
        "state": "pre-added",
        "who": ["user:sun02"],
        "prob": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**El HTML del JSON anterior se ve así: (Los siete HTML tienen una oración como esta)**

```
Es muy difícil tener una comunicación rápida y efectiva con usted.
```

**La ruta de la carpeta es esta:**

```
C:\Users\Moon\Desktop\pypractice
```

He pasado días leyendo sobre esto, se que `glob.glob` es la mejor opción, pero no puedo entenderlo. Agradecería que alguien me explicara cómo hacerlo.

**Esto fue lo que intenté:**

```py
folder = r"C:\Users\Moon\Desktop\pypractice"
files = os.listdir(folder)
for fn in files: 
    with open(os.path.join(folder, fn), 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        f_dict = json.loads(content)
        entities = f_dict['entities']
        relations = f_dict['relations']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-bd006e8c0876> in <module>
      1 for fn in files:
----> 2     with open(os.path.join(pith, fn), 'r') as f:
      3         content = f.read()
      4         f_dict = json.reads(content)
      5 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Moon\\Desktop\\pypractice\\.ipynb_checkpoints'
```

Comment: Entiendo que no tengas idea de cómo hacerlo, pero eso no quita que hayas escrito al menos un intento de leer archivos o escrito al menos alguna línea de código que indique que intentas hacer *algo*, si eso no te funciona, entonces puedes venir y preguntar específicamente eso que no te funciona, y así tal vez sea más eficiente tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: path = 'C:\Users\Moon\Desktop\pypractice'

files = []


for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.json' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    print(f)

Hice esto

Comment: ponelo en la pregunta lo que intentaste, y contanos que paso...

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya lo hice @gbianchi

Comment: `os.listdir()` te da una lista de todos los ficheros en la carpeta. Parece que algunos de ellos están protegidos contra lectura (por eso el error que obtuviste). Puedes usar `fn.endswith("json")` por ejemplo para ver si el nombre del fichero `fn` termina por `"json"` o no, para saltartelo en caso de que no

Comment: Yo escribi esto, antes del with open:   if fn.endswith(".ipynb_checkpoints"):
            continue, pero aun no me devuelve lo que necesito.

Comment: Hola @DS01, he usado tu fichero de ejemplo triplicandolo en tres ficheros con nombres diferentes y en principio tu código ejecuta sin errores. Esto confirma un problema de privilegios en algún fichero como indica @Abulafia. Podrías indicarme el criterio con el que quieres cruzar los ficheros html con los json para obtener el campo `text` de tu diccionario final?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sugiero que en la ruta de tu `.py` crees un nuevo directorio (p.e. **input**) donde ubicar tus ficheros de entrada al programa, para evitar otros ficheros que no quieras incluir en la lectura (como en tu caso .ipynb_checkpoints). Así sabes que al usar `files = os.listdir(folder)`, sólo encontrarás los ficheros de entrada que te interesan.

En este código he incluido la condición que te recomienda @Abulafia, para si aún dentro del directorio con ficheros de entrada quieres filtrar. También he incluído la creación del diccionario de salida que esperas (en lugar del campo texto he usado el nombre del fichero)

```
import os
import json

folder = "./input"
files = os.listdir(folder)

for fn in files:
    if fn.endswith("json"): #Esta condición solo permitirá entrada de ficheros que terminen en json
        with open(os.path.join(folder, fn), 'r') as f:
            dict = {}
            content = f.read()
            f_dict = json.loads(content)
            dict['file']=fn #Este campo del diccionario lo reemplazarías por tu campo texto
            dict['entities']= f_dict['entities']
            dict['relations']= f_dict['relations']
            print (dict)
```

La salida (usando tu fichero de ejemplo repetido 3 veces) es esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tomar de tu tiempo para responder, intente algo muy similar ayer, me salio parecido, pero el tuyo esta mucho mejor, el único inconveniente que estoy teniendo es que ; las palabras en español, no salen como deben. Por ejemplo:[{'start': 3, 'text': 'muy difÃ\xadcil'}].

Comment: Prueba reemplazando la línea 9 por `with open(os.path.join(folder, fn),  'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:`. El argumento `encoding='utf-8'` asegura que el archivo se lea usando la codificación correcta. Si a pesar de ello genera caracteres inválidos, es posible la codificación del fichero origen no sea UTF-8.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Lo arreglo. Si vivieras en mi país, te invitara a comer algo. :3